# My local MySQL server was temporary down for unknown reasons

Tags: linux, mysql, logging

My local MySQL server 5.5.38 (on CentOS 6.5) has been temporary down and the mysql log file was filled with this kind of details:

```
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=44
max_threads=151
thread_count=15
connection_count=15
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338508 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x35accd0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f2514201d98 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x78b76e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x493)[0x674483]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x356b40f710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x356b032925]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x356b034105]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x833550]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x833759]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x838537]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x816922]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x81720a]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x80c1d5]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7ea934]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7eaa76]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x81ff3b]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x82583e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7a01ae]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN7handler7ha_openEP5TABLEPKcii+0x3d)[0x676a9d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z21open_table_from_shareP3THDP11TABLE_SHAREPKcjjjP5TABLEb+0x537)[0x5f6837]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z10open_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP11st_mem_rootP18Open_table_context+0xc43)   [0x5519e3]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z21open_table_from_shareP3THDP11TABLE_SHAREPKcjjjP5TABLEb+0x537)[0x5f6837]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z10open_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP11st_mem_rootP18Open_table_context+0xc43)  [0x5519e3]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11open_tablesP3THDPP10TABLE_LISTPjjP19Prelocking_strategy+0x3ea)[0x5525da]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z30open_normal_and_derived_tablesP3THDP10TABLE_LISTj+0x4b)[0x552efb]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x5c5fb7]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z14get_all_tablesP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP4Item+0x6e7)[0x5d0987]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z24get_schema_tables_resultP4JOIN23enum_schema_table_state+0x22e)[0x5c141e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x4f5)[0x5bc2a5]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDPPP4ItemP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListIS1_ES2_jP8st_orderSB_S2_SB_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x162)[0x5bdff2]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP3LEXP13select_resultm+0x17c)[0x5bea7c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x57e3e7]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x206b)[0x583beb]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x1bb)[0x58634b]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x1c4d)[0x58874d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0xd2)[0x619132]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x50)[0x619240]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x356b4079d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x356b0e8b5d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f24d0ea7440): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 431546
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

I solved the problem with clearing the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 and changing the owner of /var/lib/mysql recursively to mysql:mysql. Can someone explain me what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32158, which is the top hit for open_table_from_share

If its reproducible, perhaps you should install the debuginfo package for mysql; that *might* make the callstack a bit clearer (although that would assume that gdb is the one creating the stack-trace, and I don't think it is)